# Badge for a bounty that didn't yield any answers

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I issued a bounty for a question:

[Why am I getting a "well-formedness constraint: unique attribute spec" (0xc00cee3c) error when I descend from LongListSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880464/)

It brought in zero responses.

It'd be interesting if there was a badge for that.

Maybe call it "Bounty-lost" or "bounty-tumbleweed"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is too much of an edge case to  justify a consolation badge.

Usually, two types of questions fail to get responses from a bounty:

- Bad questions (too vague ones, too broad ones....)
- Hard questions (truly *hard* problems, questions that require deep inside knowledge about the product...)

The bad ones don't deserve recognition; and a badge wouldn't help the hard questions, the niche ones are so special that really no one can answer them, get answers.

What I could support is a "discount" on running a second bounty, or making it free. That might help hard questions in very little-frequented tags.

Comment: The discount idea is pretty nice.

Comment: I really like the idea of a discount. It would have to expire of course - you shouldn't get your coupon (hehe) if 1) someone answers or 2) you revoke the bounty (can you even revoke a bounty?). It should only be for genuinely unanswered bounties.

Comment: Currently the minimum goes up if you want to add another bounty. Maybe make that extra amount "free" (so the second would be +100 for a cost of +50, the third +200 for the cost of +50, etc) if no answer was received?

Comment: This discount idea suggests that if a good question is asked on the wrong site, the OP should stick to that site and keep bumping it with discount bounties instead of asking a mod to migrate it elsewhere. (Something that [has happened](http://superuser.com/questions/992917/touchscreen-right-click-emulation-doesnt-work) to me recently, though migration did't really help).